# Mapping RDD with several comma separated fields in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new to Spark and I am going over a tutorial where a line with several fields is parsed with Scala, the code with scala is like this:

```
val pass = lines.map(_.split(",")).
map(pass=>(pass(15),pass(7).toInt)).
reduceByKey(_+_)
```

where `pass` is data recevied from socketTextStream (its SparkStreams). I am new to Spark and want to use Java to have the same result. I have decalared `JavaReceiverInputDStream` using:

```
JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = jssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999);
```

I came up with two possible solutions:

1. using flatMap:

   `JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(
       new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
       @Override public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
           return Arrays.asList(x.split(","));
       }
   });`

But it doesn't seem right since the result is breaking the CSV to words without any order.

2. Using map (compilation error), This looks like the appropriate solution but I am not able to extract the fields 15 and 7 using:

   `JavaDStream<List<String>> words = lines.map(
       new Function<String, List<String>>() {
       public List<String> call(String s) {
           return Arrays.asList(s.split(","));
       }
   });`

This idea fails when i try to map List`<String>` => Tuple2`<String, Int>`

The mapping code is:

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> pairs = words.map(
new PairFunction<List<String>, String, Integer>() {
  public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(List<String> s) throws Exception {
    return new Tuple2(s.get(15), 6);
  }
});
```

The error:

method map in class

```
org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.AbstractJavaDStreamLike`<T,This,R>` cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function`<java.util.List`<java.lang.String>`,R>`
[ERROR] found: `<anonymous org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction`<java.util.List`<java.lang.String>`,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>`>`
[ERROR] reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that argument type `<anonymous org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction`<java.util.List`<java.lang.String>`,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>`>` conforms to formal parameter type org.apache.spark.api.java.
```

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code. It will get require field from String.

```
JavaDStream<String> lines = { ..... };
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> pairs = lines.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String t) throws Exception {
        String[] words = t.split(",");
        return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(words[15],Integer.parseInt(words[7]));
    }
});
```